# How to use Hijri Calender in MVC

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-widgets, hijri

I have a MVC project and I want to use a customized Hijri Calender to be selected by the dd-MM-yyyy returned from database and enables the user to be a Date-picker to change Date values if needed . I searched for it but I didn't find.

Comment: Maybe [jQuery Calendar](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html) and [jQuery Calendar Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html) by Keith Wood can help you.